# Sharing image makes phone very unstable

Tags: images, performance, motorola, share-menu

I think that Motorola One can be considered a quite powerful phone with its octa-core 2.0 GHz Snapdragon 625 and 3 GB or RAM. It also produces a fairly small images of 4160x3120 pixels and approx. 3-5 MB in size. Based on that specs, I'd say that sharing image should be an instant experience.

Yet, in fact, it is a nightmare in my case:

- attaching single image to Gmail (to share it via email) takes 20-30 seconds, sometimes more and often hangs Gmail itself for a moment (i.e. I can write an address or message content during adding of image) or permanently,
- attaching image to Messages app (to share it via MMS message) takes 30-50 seconds or even more, often hangs Messages app and on a few rare occasions hanged entire phone.

Is there *anything* I can do about this except for uninstalling Gmail and Google Messages and start using another email and messages app?

<sub>BTW: We *could* say that my slow network (which is not slow) can be considered as a contributing factor in case of Gmail. But could it also explain MMS experience? Which has nearly nothing to do about data transfer over Internet during MMS message creation?</sub>

Comment: When you send the image via GMail does the recipient get the original image or ist it somehow processed (resized recompressed,...)?

Comment: Does this happen with all source apps or only some apps? I remember [Wikipedia app needed to download the image first before sharing to other apps (including uploading the image again on Gmail case)](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/230336/44325).

Comment: @Robert No, neither I (sender) see any dialog asking me to resize image prior to sending it nor the recipient gets it modified. It is 1:1 / 100% exactly the same image as captured by my camera. There's no processing AFAIK.

Comment: @AndrewT. I cannot answer you this question directly, because I am using orignal (stock) Messages app and Gmail on all brands and kinds of Motorolas that I've been using for years. However, I am pretty sure that this has nothing to do with downloading or network speed, because I have it quite fast. For example yesterday I managed to download and install two huge game updates (approx. 1 GB each) in just a few minutes. I have a stable approx. 30-50 Mbps upstream and downstream so downloading or uploading these images during share shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @trejder Why don't you just send an image top yourself and compare the files? That would be the easiest way to determine if the image is processed.

Comment: @Robert Seems my comment is confusing to you, sorry for that. These images are 100% the same. I am sending them via email to myself only. And I am doing so only when I am too busy (or too lazy) to do this via cable. But I am sure that there is no processing and image is changed in no way. So, it lands on my PC exactly the same, no matter, if I use Gmail or USB cable.

Comment: you could try if other app will make a difference (i personally prefer mail.ru for sending pictures as attachments, no size limit)